# Trying to find out how sockets and nod.js works

Tags: socket.io

I have been using php, mysqli and Ajax to work on a live chat web site. But recently I'm was told that sockets and node.js works better. How true is it?.

I have actually looked into it but I'm pretty confused.  How do I get to save my client data since Their is no database server?

Is it possible to work on socket.io and node.js in my wamp server?

Don't really understand how node.js works.

Pls help?

Comment: html <-> js <-> socket.io client <-> socket.io server + mysql package in node.js <-> mysql

Comment: And YES, socket.io is much better than php and ajax, since it's a bi-directional communication, your client can receive message from server instantly without having to pull new messages from server.